# how can i get all the rows id's in sheet or report including all pages?

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api-2.0

```
report = ss.Reports.get_report(report_id,page_size=5000,)
row_dict={}
count = 0
for row in report.rows:
    row_dict[count] = (row.sheet_id, row.id)
    count +=1
```

i have 2 pages in one report but I am getting only pages 1 details, how can i get page 2 details?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters to retrieve the other page. [Here is a link to query params](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#query-strings) in the Smartsheet API docs.

If you want a specific page you can use `page=2`, or if you want to grab everything you can use `includeAll=true`. In Python I believe its `include_all=True`.